# Configure running website WordPress that redirect on install page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have configured running website to a new hosting company. When i run website then its automatically redirects me to install.php, but i already config database.

I rechecked config file and table_prefix that are fine.

Comment: might be cache issue.

Comment: Have you changed option table url entries

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam : i have transfer only hosting so url might be same.

Comment: Refer this url https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2497/WordPress-Redirecting-to-wp-adminorinstallphp.html

Comment: @urfusion : i have also check on chrome incognito window.

Comment: @Ravi please check your home url in the wp_options table, that should be pointing to the new URL of your new hosting

Comment: @funkysoul : i have check home url that is perfect.

Comment: Database config, wp config, user credentials, everything correct?

Comment: @funkysoul : yes everything fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long I found solution Host server Mysql query speed <15000 per hour.